# How can I apply onInvalid but to a whole form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how can I find out that the form is filled out incorrectly, for example

```html
<form action="">
<input type="text" required oninvalid="invalid()">
<input type="text" required oninvalid="invalid()">
<button>send</button>
</form>
<script>
function invalid(){
    alert("invalid field")
}
</script>
```

This code will trigger an alert on every incorrect field, but I only need one event that the form is not correct. That is, regardless of the number of incorrectly filled fields, onInvalid should occur only once. How can I implement this

Comment: You can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/mj73k9qy/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) method on the form itself.

```html
<form action="" >
<input type="text" required >
<input type="text" required >
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">send</button>
</form>
<script>
function submitForm(){
   if(!document.querySelector('form').reportValidity()){
   alert("invalid field");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to somehow optimize the validation chec? It turns out that the validation check happens two times - on checkValidity and submit (sorry if Im wrong :) ). Can I return the value of the result of a validation check on form.submit or its not possible?